# Reveal all non-printing ANSI characters and metacharacters in a Javascript string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm receiving piped stdout output from a multitude of fairly random shell processes, all as input (stdin) on a single node.js process. For debugging and for parsing, I need to be handle different special character codes that are being piped into the process. It would really help me to see invisible characters (for debugging mostly) and to deal with them accordingly once I've identified the patterns in which they are used.

Given a javascript string with ANSI special characters `\u001b*` and/or metacharacters such as `\n`, `\t`, `\r` etc., how can one reveal these special characters so they aren't actually rendered, but rather exposed as their code value instead.

For example, let's say I have the following string printed in **green** (can't show the green colour on SO):

```
    This is a string.
We are now using the green color.
```

I would like to be able to do a `console.log` (for example) on this string and have it replace the non-printing characters, metacharacters/newlines, color codes etc with their ANSI codes:

```
"\u001b[32m\tThis is a string.\nWe are now using the green color.\n"
```

I can do something like the following, but it is too specific, hard-coded, and inefficient:

```
line = line.replace(/[\f]/g, '\\n');
line = line.replace(/\u0008/g, '\\b');
line = line.replace(/\u001b|\u001B/g, '\\u001b');
line = line.replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g, '\\n');
...
```

Comment: Reveal in what way? (also, regexes are not a good tool for this task.)

Comment: Why not just loop through the string one character at a time and look at each value in the string to see if it's anything you want to treat as a special character and then build a new, modified string as you go.

Comment: Hummm, that sounds very slow... this needs to be done as efficiently as possible. And why isn't regex a good tool for this kind of thing?

Comment: How does your solution seem crazy and imprecise?

Comment: escape or decodeURIComponent will change non-wordy chars into more than one char...

Comment: Do you somehow think a regex isn't just looping through the whole string?

Comment: @Bergi Well, I'd need to know all the possible codes that could ever exist, I'd imagine. And in testing, I can't seem to identify every single possibility. For example, there are hundreds of ANSI escape code variants.

Comment: You HAVE to know either all the character codes you want to replace or all the codes you don't want to replace.  If you don't know either of those, then go back and work on defining your problem before any code can be written.

Comment: Well, if you want to replace them with their names, then yes - you need to *know* these names?!

Comment: You should describe what the actual _problem_ you are trying to solve here is first of all.

Comment: @jfriend00 I actually didn't know that regex wasn't looping through the string. But I do now! :)

Comment: @CBroe I thought I was doing that, but I edited the question to clarify with a more concrete explanation of the problem! I hope that feels better.

Comment: @ArjunMehta: I was more expecting an explanation as to _why_ this has to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version that loops through the string, tests to see if it's a normal printable character and, if not, looks it up in a special table for your own representation of that character and if not found in the table, displays whatever default representation you want:

```
var tagKeys = {
    '\n': 'New Line \n',
    '\u0009': 'Tab',
    '\u2029': 'Line Separator'
    /* and so on */
};

function tagSpecialChars(str) {
    var output = "", ch, replacement;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        ch = str.charAt(i);
        if (ch < ' ' || ch > '~') {
            replacement = tagKeys[ch];
            if (replacement) {
                ch = replacement;
            } else {
                // default value
                // could also use charCodeAt() to get the numeric value                     
                ch = '*****';
            }
        }
        output += ch;
    }
    return output;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/bCYa4/

This is obviously not some fancy regex solution, but you said performance was important and you rarely find the best performing operation using a regex and certainly not if you're going to use a whole bunch of them.  Plus every regex replace has to loop through the whole string anyway.

This workman-like solution just loops through the input string once and lets you customize the display conversion for any non-printable character you want and also determine what you want to display when it's a non-printable character that you don't have a special display representation for.

Comment: I chose this answer because of its performance advantage. Thank you! An improvement on this might be to make `tagKeys` dynamic, and added to when it discovers a new character code value ala Oriol's answer with `charCodeAt`. This would actually best suit what I asked for, but this is the best general algorithm that can be used to get at that. I appreciate you taking the time to answer this despite my ambiguous question. :)

Comment: @jsfriend http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-brute-force/3 I modified your code a tad to include the charCodeAt bit from Oriol to create a dynamic list that grows when it encounters new codes. Please tell me what you think!

Comment: @ArjunMehta - Just so you understand, putting the dynamically generated names into `tagKeys` is purely done as a cache for performance reasons.  If no special characters were repeated, this would actually be slower.  If several are repeated, the cache might actually improve your performance by saving you some time in generating the string representation for repeated characters - the gain/loss in performance will depend upon the character of the input string.  But, it's not needed to make the code do what you want as you can just generate the name any time the code is encountered.

Comment: hi! Yes I understand this. It's useful for my particular case, as strings will vary constantly and will be quite unpredictable in how many and which special characters might be used, and the application will have extended uptime. so having a cache of special characters to match will be very useful for long term performance. Thanks again!

Comment: @ArjunMehta - OK, you're good to go then.  Glad you got what you needed.

Comment: I did, thank you. I'm just surprised others didn't quite see the value in the question :( It seems like it would be such a useful thing to know how to do.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var map = {  // Special characters
    '\\': '\\',
    '\n': 'n',
    '\r': 'r',
    '\t': 't'
};
str = str.replace(/[\\\n\r\t]/g, function(i) {
    return '\\'+map[i];
});
str = str.replace(/[^ -~]/g, function(i){
    return '\\u'+("000" + i.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-4);
});
```

Comment: How do you think this performs?  You're creating N regexp objects and doing N regular expression replacement operations.  That doesn't seem like a recipe for good performance which the OP said was important.

Comment: @jfriend00 But those only replace special characters that should be escaped differently (`\n`, `\t`, ...), there shouldn't be lots of them. Most characters will be escaped in a single replacement operation.

Comment: The OP shows at least 10 characters with special names they want to show and implies there may be many more.

Comment: @jfriend00 OP replaces `\t` with `Tab` and then says that the desired output is `\t`, ignoring the list of replacements. So I ignore it too.

Comment: I guess that part of the question is unclear since they provide code that puts in "Tab", but a result that puts in "\t".  Who knows?  My point stands that multiple regex operations are rarely the highest performing way to go.

Comment: See http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-brute-force for a rough look at performance.  The non-regex method looks like it's 14x faster.  Results will vary based on the input and how many special characters are in the table, but I think this shows the general idea about performance.

Comment: @jfriend00 Updated, now it's only two replacement operations.

Comment: @jfriend00 [Updated jsperf](http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-brute-force/2). I doubled the speed, but your solution is still mush faster :)

Comment: @Oriol Thank you so much for your answer! It's actually the closest to what I was asking for at a general level. But jfriend00 makes a good point in that it's not the most efficient general algorithm. But the secret sauce in your answer (the `charCodeAt` bit) can be combined with his answer for a super efficient, dynamic solution. I will do a jsperf on my final solution tomorrow morning :) Thank you again!

Comment: @ArjunMehta Glad to have helped :) Let me know when you finish your jsperf.

Comment: @Oriol here you go: http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-brute-force/3 have a look and tell me what you think!